# Is there a way to replace the window after user clicks button?

Tags: javascript

So id like a way for when the user presses my button it replaces their window with a new URL.

```
<button id="form-submit" type="submit">Next</button>
```

Comment: `window.location` [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) or `window.location.href` [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href)

Comment: What is the motive for using a button? For simple usage, I think it is better to use an `<a>` and style it to *look like* a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window.location.href and set it to the new URL.

```js
document.querySelector('#form-submit')
    .addEventListener('click', () => window.location.href = "https://example.com");
```

```html
<button id="form-submit" type="submit">Next</button>
```